# Return multiple images from PHP to Javascript

Tags: php, ajax, image

How can I return an array of images from my PHP server application?

I would like to be able to access and display them from my JavaScript/AJAX call, as below:

My GET query:

```
$.get("http://localhost:80/index/index.php?r=myPics", function(data, status){
       
});
```

I don't want to return the filenames of these images and do a separate call because the images are stored in a profile-specific directory on the server end. Eg `/images/<profile id>/1.jpg`, and thus security would be an issue if a user could therefore modify the profile id.

My end goal is to display all 10 profile images on the one page with minimal network requests, and display them in order from 1 to 10.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks,

Comment: use inline images? `src="data:image/png;base64, ..."`

Comment: As in return the contents of all 10 images? Isn't that a bit clunky? It'll fill up the console....

Comment: you don't want to expose the files, yet still display them... the image content has to be delivered in any case, no matter how it's done.

Comment: You still have security issue. If you don't show id it does not mean you solved it. You should create a handler which gets auth header and id. There your logic should decide is it allowed or not. Thus, use handlers instead of direct links.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['profil_id'];

// Create array
$a = [];

// Get list of files and add to array

// Add to array
$a[] = '/images/'.$id.'/1.jpg';
$a[] = '/images/'.$id.'/2.jpg';
$a[] = '/images/'.$id.'/3.jpg';

// Return json string
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Truru, thanks, but I don't want to return the image path name as stated above.